# how to use a predefined variable into gql query using apollo client

Tags: graphql

I have a query to which i would like to insert a variable:

this is the query :

```
query = gql`{getStuff{outputs(filter: ["10_lorries", "3_cars"]){id, brand}}}`
const {data, error, loading} = useQuery(query)
```

which by itself works fine, but what if instead of explicitely passing the array I had it defined in a variable and want to pass it to the query?

```
const vehicles= ["10_lorries", "3_cars"]
```

when trying this data returns an undefined:

```
query = gql`{getStuff{outputs(filter: vehicles){id, brand}}}`
```

I am struggling a bit to understand how to pass the variable into the gql query..

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variable through [options](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#options) provided by apollo [useQuery hooks](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#usequery):

```
query = gql`{getStuff{outputs(filter: myFilter){id, brand}}}`

const vehicles= ["10_lorries", "3_cars"]

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(query, {
  variables: { myFilter: vehicles },
});
```